# Control relative size of ggplot points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to control the relative size of the `size = clarity` argument in the following ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
diamonds %>% 
sample_n(100) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = depth, y = price, color = cut, size = clarity)) +
geom_point()
```

I tried to play with `shape = 19`, moved `size` inside `geom_point()` to no avail. I just want the shapes to be smaller in the plot (not the legend). Is there a way?

Comment: I think shape for cut and color for clarity might be a better visualisation. Also, sizes in the plot and in the legend will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add:

```
+ scale_size_discrete(range = c(0.5, 4))
```

and experiment with values for range. The default is c(1, 6).

Note the warning message regarding size and discrete variables.

Comment: fantastic! This works and I had no idea this argument existed.